# Angular: HTTP client converting a tree like data structure

Tags: angular, angular-httpclient

I have from the server the following structure (as appropriate JSON structure)

```
Orga1
| + Department1
| |  + Role1
| |  + Role2
| + Department2
| |  + Role10
| |  + Role11
Orga 2
| + DepartmentAB
| |  + RoleAB1
...
```

I was thinking to have in an object in Angular like

```
export interface Organization {
  name: string;
  lstDeparments: Department [];
}
export interface Department {
  name: string;
  lstRoles: string [];
}
```

But somehow I have no real clue how to set up the matching interface in Angular. Because the attribute `name` is dynamically changing (e.g. `Orga1`, `Orga2`) and the list of attributes needs to be filled as well dynamically with the content.

Any ideas how to setup the `interface` properly? (to have automatic conversion)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a specific syntax for this kind of data structure :

```
interface Payload {
  [key: string]: Orga;
}

interface Orga {
  [key: string]: Department;
}

interface Department {
  [key: string]: Role;
}
```

If you want the list of Orgas, you have to iterate on an object, not on an array.

You can do this with `Object.keys` or in more recent browsers (or if you have a polyfill), `Object.entries` :

```
const orgas = Object.keys(payload).map(key => payload[key]);
const orgas = Object.entries(payload).map(([key, value]) => value);
```

You can also use [generation function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/function*) through `Symbol.iterator` to iterate over your objects, but I think it's a bit overkill :

```js
const payload = {
  orga1: { name: 'orga 1' },
  orga2: { name: 'orga 2' },
  [Symbol.iterator]: function *() {
    for (const key of Object.keys(this)) {
      yield this[key];
    }
  }
};

for (const value of payload) {
  console.log(value);
}
```

Comment: (you can of course add other properties such as "name", it's just that those that aren't recognized will be considered as a sub-interface)

Comment: @ashish.gd from the given tructure, it doesn't seem like it. The payload contains a list of Orgas, which are all named. So it's not an array, it's an object containing dynamic properties, that are each a sub-interface.

Comment: Yes, my bad. I read it incorrectly. Deleting my comment to avoid any confusion to OP or anyone else.

Comment: Reponse come quicker than I could implement and think about. Couldn't accept the answer earlier :-) Thx this works great +1

Comment: Although the implementation works I have tiny problems with the solution :-/. Namely how to get a list of e.g. `Organisation`. Trying `Payload.map(item=>Object.keys(item)[0]);` is a `valid` (?) idea in debug - but in Angular I get a compile error cuz `map` is not provided in `Orga`.

Comment: @LeO I have updated my answer to show you how to iterate over it

Comment: @trichetriche: Thx. The `generation function` sounds great but I cannot place it inside an `interface`. The other approach with the entries/keys gives me the results I was looking for. Thx again.

Comment: You can add it to your payload through `payload[Symbol.iterator] = function*()...` if you need to, just keep that in mind, just in case :)